Tiny MCE Editor cuts script and iframe tags in spite of extended_valid_elements settings
Next.js 14 App Router project.
I am trying to implement TINYMCE Editor and mostly it all works fine. It saves the data and displays loaded data from the server.
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react'
import { useController, Control } from 'react-hook-form'

interface TinyMCEEditorProps {
  name: string
  control: Control<any>
  initialValue?: string
  height?: number
  menubar?: boolean
  plugins?: string[]
  toolbar?: string
  contentStyle?: string
  onEditorChange?: (content: string) => void
}

const TinyMCEEditor: React.FC<TinyMCEEditorProps> = ({
  name,
  control,
  initialValue = '<p>This is the initial content of the editor.</p>',
  height = 500,
  menubar = false,
  plugins = [
    'advlist',
    'autolink',
    'lists',
    'link',
    'image',
    'charmap',
    'preview',
    'anchor',
    'searchreplace',
    'visualblocks',
    'code',
    'fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime',
    'media',
    'table',
    'code',
    'help',
    'wordcount',
  ],
  toolbar = 'undo redo | blocks | bold italic forecolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
    'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | code | help',
  contentStyle = 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px } img { max-width: 500px; height: auto; }',
  onEditorChange,
}) => {
  const editorRef = useRef<any>(null)
  const { field } = useController({
    name,
    control,
    defaultValue: initialValue,
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      editorRef.current.setContent(field.value)
    }
  }, [field.value])

  const apiKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TINYMCE_API_KEY

  return (
    <Editor
      apiKey={apiKey}
      onInit={(_evt, editor) => {
        editorRef.current = editor
        editor.setContent(field.value)
      }}
      initialValue={field.value}
      init={{
        height,
        menubar,
        plugins,
        toolbar,
        content_style: contentStyle,
        extended_valid_elements:
          'script[src|async|defer|type|charset],iframe[src|width|height|allowfullscreen|loading|referrerpolicy|style|frameborder|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|name|align|longdesc|onclick|ondblclick|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseover|onmousemove|onmouseout|onkeypress|onkeydown|onkeyup]',
        valid_elements: '*[*]',
        valid_children: '+body[script|iframe]',
        media_live_embeds: true,
      }}
      onEditorChange={(content) => {
        field.onChange(content)
        if (onEditorChange) {
          onEditorChange(content)
        }
      }}
    />
  )
}

export default TinyMCEEditor

I have my extended_valid_elements setup, but still, for example, the following snippet
<table
  border="1"
  width="100%"
  cellpadding="10"
>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="map">
      <td colspan="2">
        <iframe
          allowfullscreen=""
          height="450"
          loading="lazy"
          referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
          src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?URL_COMES_HERE"
          style="border: 0"
          width="1720"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td
        class="widget"
        colspan="2"
      >
        <script
          async="async"
          src="URL_COMES_HERE"
          charset="utf-8"
          type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

is replaced with (note, that it even removes the entire row, where <script> was used)
<table
  border="1"
  width="100%"
  cellpadding="10"
>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="map">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

My usage in the form looks like:
<TinyMCEEditor
  name='en_body'
  control={form.control}
  onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
/>

Did I miss something in the documentation: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements ?
The stackoverflow asks me to put more text here, but there is nothing else I can add.
I played with the init options, but it seems I miss something somewhere else:
      init={{
        height,
        menubar,
        plugins: [...plugins, 'noneditable'],
        toolbar,
        content_style: contentStyle,
        extended_valid_elements:
          'script[src|async|defer|type|charset],iframe[src|width|height|allowfullscreen|loading|referrerpolicy|style|frameborder|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|name|align|longdesc]',
        valid_elements: '*[*]',
        valid_children:
          '+body[style],+body[script],+div[h2|span|p|a|table|script],+a[div|script]',
        allow_script_urls: true,
        allow_html_in_named_anchor: true,
        paste_as_text: false,
        media_live_embeds: true,
      }}

